# Is it ok and how do I remove Windows Update installation files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, disk-space

Whenever Windows updates, it sometimes/most times downloads installation files, and then uses those files to install the update onto the OS (correct me if I'm wrong on this assumption).  What I want to know is if those files aren't crucial to the operation of the OS and can be deleted.  If so, then where can I locate those files and delete them?

Comment: Look at [this](http://blog.remyservices.net/2008/03/19/cleaning-your-system/) page for some info on system cleaning on updates. It doesn't talk about all updates but it could help you out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's safe to delete the SoftwareDistribution folder which keeps the stuff you describe.

[Read this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822798#) which describes how...

Comment: there is no method 10 on that link